# Desrialize Enum List in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, enums, spring-data-jpa

So, I have a Model defined where I want to have a particular variable as ENUM.
Now I have defined it in the model like this.

```
  @Type(
    type = "array",
    parameters = { @Parameter(name = ListArrayType.SQL_ARRAY_TYPE, value = "member_role") }
  )
  @Column(name = "access_roles", columnDefinition = "member_role[]")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private List<ProjectMemberRole> accessRoles;
```

The Enum is

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public enum ProjectMemberRole {
  LEAD("lead", 4),
  COLLABORATOR("collaborator", 3),
  PARTICIPANT("participant", 2),
  VIEWER("viewer", 1);

  private final String value;
  private final Integer level;

  @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING)
  public static ProjectMemberRole forString(String value) {
    return stream(ProjectMemberRole.values())
      .filter(v -> v.value.equals(value))
      .findFirst()
      .orElse(null);
  }

  @Override
  @JsonValue
  public String toString() {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

Even. though I am able to create, when I fetch I get this error

```
"No enum constant project.model.ProjectMemberRole.collaborator; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant project.model.ProjectMemberRole.collaborator"
```

So, it seems its getting serialized but not getting de-serialized. What should I be doing in this situation?

EDIT:
I was checking if we have a single element instead of an Array.
If we have a single value then it goes with ENUM Name `COLLABORATOR` but if we send it as List then it becomes `collaborator`

So for some reason it is saving JSON value for enum.

```
  @Column(name = "access_roles")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ProjectMemberRole[] accessRoles;

  @Column(name = "access_role", columnDefinition = "text")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ProjectMemberRole accessRole;
```

Comment: What are the values currently present in you database?

Comment: you should be serializing the  COLLABORATOR  instead of value in DB

Comment: `collaborator` is present in the database. I thought it should have pushed COLLABORATOR?
Enums which are not in List work fine.

Answer (score 0):

enums are usually expected to be upper-case during deserialization. You can enable it for Jackson using

```
objectMapper.enable(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_ENUMS);
```

when you configure your ObjectMapper.

Comment: If we have a single value then it goes with ENUM Name `COLLABORATOR` but if we send it as List then it becomes `collaborator`